# K6 Load Testing - Can you specify whether the output metric for data received/sent is shown in kB or MB?

Tags: k6

K6 Load Testing

At the end of testing, the following metrics are shown:

```
data_received..............: 1.4 MB  44 kB/s
data_sent..................: 214 kB  6.7 kB/s
```

In the above example, data_received is shown in MB whereas data_sent is shown in kB.

Is it possible to specify that these values are ALWAYS shown in kB or MB?

This will make comparing values easier as we know that we are comparing like with like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such option, and while it will probably be possible to add I would argue this is better done using the [json export summary](https://k6.io/docs/results-visualization/json#summary-export) where this is just a number.

There is also a [proposal](https://github.com/loadimpact/k6/issues/1319#issuecomment-579462738) (the whole ticket is about problems with the current summary output) to have a way to have user (and standard) templates for this output where this might be possible, but nobody has started working on it.